# How could I show an hidden div when a page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a view with a div that have a unique ID named "thumb" with `display:none` as style. Now on loading of another page I wish to show it, and also check if that div was already shown. I tried without success with this:

```
<div onload="music_player()">
--
</div>

<script>
function music_player() {
    document.getElementById('thumb').style.display = 'block'; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery makes this pretty easy for you. Use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show your element is your function in a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler. Additionally, the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector makes it easy to determine if an element is currently hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isShown = $("#thumb:visible").length > 0;
  if (!isShown) {
    $("#thumb").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to take advantage of jQuery's `.is()` function whenever possible

So the previous answer could be shortened to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $thumb = $('#thumb');
  if (!$thumb.is(':visible')) {
    $thumb.show();
  }
});
```